# How to close a MdiChild Form right after opening it?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

We can close a Mdiform by Me.close() written in a control like Button's event.
Can we close a form right after opening it?

According to what I know after opening a form the pointer goes to Form.Load event.
I tried writing Me.close in Form.Load and Form.Activated but

> I got error describing me.close won't work while CreateHandler()
>   event.

I am doing this because I created something like if say Public variable bool as Boolean = false then form won't open.
I can put it before initializing form in mdi parent and it works for me but a form can be initialized from many different points. Like from MdiParent and from another MdiChild too and I have to put `if bool = false then exit sub` everywhere. If I can put it in the form then I can save some LOC.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try putting it under the `Form_Shown` event.

Comment: Errors like this are usually due to the code in the constructor not completing.  Check the constructor.  You may have to move some of the constructor code to the Load() event.

Comment: @jdweng I am not going to change in constructors. I want easy way and writing in form_shown actually worked.

Comment: @preciousbetine `Form_Shown` worked but it opens the form and then shows message. Is there any way form not shown first??? This will also work for me though.

Comment: What do you mean by *Is there any way form not shown first?*

Comment: @preciousbetine Oh sorry, I gave you less data. Actually I wrote the code like `if bool = false then msgbox(hello) : me.close` in from.shown event and it worked for me. However the form loads up(yes it will load obvious) and then the message comes up on the form like a showdialog. On clicking messagebox okay button the form closes too. That's all what I want. But I want to see just the msgbox and not form in background. Current answer will also work for me and thank you for that but if possible I can just show the msgbox and not form then it'll be good.

Comment: @preciousbetine Your answer is good for me and will do my work but if possible to just show msgbox and not the form. However the user cannot interact with the form and that's all I want.User has to interact msgbox ok btn and on clicking ok btn form closes too and its good.

Comment: what about creating a subnew and reading the boolean to determine if you want to move on to open a form or not? (this is from memory but I'm pretty sure it was called sub new)

Comment: it's actually Sub Main() in VB.Net

Comment: @CharlesMay Can you give me an example? Is it like the answer given by HardCode below??

Comment: Yes, pretty much. I took my answer off because I had originally thought you were talking about upon starting the program. Once I saw it had to do with opening a child form, then HardCode's answer was more fitting to your question.

Comment: @CharlesMay Ya but I don't think so. I have to write it on every part of project where the form is opening. I guess the answer by preciousbetine is better for me. I have to write it for just once.

Comment: No, you have to write that routine where you have access to it and call THAT routine any time you want to open the child form. The routine is written once, the call to it (1 line of code) is written whenever you need to check the boolean before opening the child form. If this is a case where the boolean is set in scope, pass the boolean to the routine. Still only a single call.

Comment: @CharlesMay Ya that's good Idea but still I have create a new sub for every form. Like I have 3 forms and all opening from many different spots. Can I call form name something like `ShowMdiChildren(formName as Mdichild)` this???? And add it in the line `Dim f as new formName` ???

Comment: I don't think you can pass a form to use like that. You could however pass the formname as a string and add a select case after the boolean check and open the appropriate form that way I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You should be checking whether or not to create and show the form long before you actually show the form. In the code that instantiates the form, put a check to see if you should even create the form. You don't want to check whether or not to show a form in a Form itself after you're already showing it.

For example, this (pseudocode) could be in your MDI Parent form:

```
Private Sub ShowMdiChildForm(etc etc)

' Variable "x" is your Boolean to determine whether or not to show the form.
If x = True Then
    Dim f as new MdiChildForm
    f.Show
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I did this before. But consider that this form is opening from 20 spots of a project. So I have to write it like `if x = true then etc etc` on all 20 spots. So I want easy way to write in the form and it checks when it opens up. Your answer is not feasible to me.

Comment: I found writing in form_shown event as a convenient way.

Comment: `i did this before. but...` HardCode's example is a sub that you would call, it already handles the if x = true so you should just be able to call ShowMdiChildForm those 20 times. To me, this would be less code than instantiating a new form and showing it 20 times.